# How do I add a dependency to the android gradle task 'test'?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've introduced a dependency for my unit tests to a custom task I've written in gradle. In android-gradle v1.2.3 the unit test task is named `test`. So I assumed you add a dependency with `test.dependsOn`. Gradle doesn't like that.

Error:

```
 C:\coding\source\testapp\app\build.gradle
 Error:(30, 0) Could not find property 'test' on project ':app'.
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nilzor.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}

task myTask() {
}

test.dependsOn 'mytask'
```

Where do I go wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you see the `test` task after running `gradle tasks`?

Comment: yep: "test - Run unit tests for all variants."

Comment: Could you please try: `project.test.dependsOn my Task`?

Comment: @opal: Same error :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution: Wrap it in

```
afterEvaluate {
    test.dependsOn 'mytask'
}
```

Comment: +100 if i could!! I still don't understand groovy syntax, how to read it and how to apply it to my custom needs